# How to pass a View from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view

How can I go about passing a **View** \ **Layout** to another Activity?

I've tried:

```
LinearLayout myView = new LinearLayout(mContext);  
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("myView", (Serializable) myView);  
startActivity(intent);
```

But this won't work.

Is there any creative way to go around this?

Thank you all in advance.

---

---

**UPDATE**

I'm building a modular framework, constrained by MVC framework best practice rules. Different Activities will perform different specialized functions, and will have different looks. A module would only have to pass a **View/ Layout**, and the rest is automated, depending on the Activity the **View/ Layout** is passed to. Making work easier.

**ALSO**, an illustration in Java would best illustrate an ideal solution. However, any type of suggestion format would help and would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Why you want to pass a view separately?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Aditya. The question is a simple sample of a complex problem. The question would be less understandable if all the problem details were put up.

Comment: If you have to use the same view then why you are not using include tag to copy the same or can use the fragment.

Comment: I think you are going about your problem in a wrong way though. You pretty much never need to pass a full view. There is no reason to.

Comment: Shared Element Transitions are a way to achieve this

Comment: Can you use a view inside an activity if that view has context to another activity?

Comment: **Source Activity** -
1. Save the view related data, this will be used by the other activity to update the view.
2. Bundle the data and the view resource id.
3. pass it in the intent.

**Destination Activity** -
1. Extract layout resource from the intent. Inflate the layout resource
2. extract the data from the intent
3. Update the view

Comment: Thanks for the response FierceFox. Could you please illustrate on how to go about it with **Shared Element Transitions** @FierceFox

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev i've just read your update. shared transition wont help you here. sry

Comment: Doesn't make sense for me. Why do you want to share a View with different Activities? What you should do is to pass the data.

Comment: Pass the properties of the View and Create the View in another activity.